# ServiceStack.Redis authentication Redis Sentinel + Redis

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

**The problem:**

It is not obvious how to correctly authenticate with:

- sentinels
- redis instances themselves

when using the ServiceStack.Redis solution.

[According to the docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/Authentication) a proper way to provide a password for redis/sentinel is to set it via URLs in the following manner:

```
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(new[] {"password@localhost:26381"})
```

This works fine, but how do I provide a password for the redis connections themselves?
The password I've specified in the URL will not be copied over to redis connections.

I've found a workaround, that seems to be working, but I'm not sure if it will actually cover all the possible cases:

```
//Get the original factory
var clientFactory = RedisConfig.ClientFactory;
//Decorate it with the logic that sets a password. 
RedisConfig.ClientFactory = c =>
{
    c.Password = "password";
    return clientFactory.Invoke(c);
};

//Continue to initialize sentinels
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(new[] {"password@localhost:26379"});
```

It seems like this will actually fix the problem and will provide a password to the connections to redis instances (not sentinels).

**The question is:** is this the recommended way of doing it? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [RedisSentinel HostFilter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#custom-redis-connection-string) to customize the connection string for the individual hosts the sentinel connects to, e.g:

```
sentinel.HostFilter = host => $"password@{host}";
```

Comment: Hi mythz. Will it apply to both sentinels and redis servers or only to sentinels?

Comment: If I understood correctly - this is how it is supposed to look like

var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(new[] {"sentinelpassword@localhost:26379"})
{
    HostFilter = host => $"redispassword@{host}",
};

Is that correct?

Comment: @DmitryKotov No it's just a filter for redis instance hosts, yes you'd need to configure both.

Comment: As a side question in the same topic - will the same sentinel password apply for sentinels discovered by `ScanForOtherSentinels` feature?

Comment: @DmitryKotov It doesn't so I've just added a `SentinelHostFilter` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/771870d7c65880c9bb461242cffd5b52ac57a170) for the next version (should be out tomorrow).